# Where to post: Rinkeby Authenticated Faucet down with respect to Twitter?

Tags: testnets, bug

When attempting to use the [Rinkeby Authenticated Faucet](https://faucet.rinkeby.io/) from Chrome or FF, I just get the error:
`zlib: invalid header`

It's not due to time limits (not even close), the Tweet post includes the address and the address only, and the CAPTCHA is done correctly (many times in trying to debug).  While debugging, I saw a Google+ account post get funded, but something seems to be broken with the Twitter API use.
**Where would such issues get properly posted?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is already tracked by issue [#15635](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/15635).

While it's being looked into, the alternatives are to use either Google+ or Facebook.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this [faucet](https://faucets.blockxlabs.com/?utm_source=stackoverflow), it is meant to be universal, multiple networks

Comment: +1, thanks for the answer. Note that this faucet has limited funds on various networks, such as Rinkeby, especially compared to the official faucet's funding account.